# When developing code in a submodule, how to push changes to the remote repo?

Tags: git, github, boost, git-submodules

I'm tinkering with a library which is a part of a larger library collection, where the larger collection is a git(hub) repo, and so is the individual library; but - you have to clone the entire collection, with the specific library as a subrepo, just in order to work on the individual library, for various reasons (see my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714581/how-can-i-build-an-individual-boost-library-forked-cloned-from-git) about setting this up).

So, I'm making changes to the repo code, which is checked out as a submodule. But - I notice I'm on a "detached head", i.e. if I commit - I can't just push it to the relevant branch on the library's remote repository.

- Can I arrange it so that commits do not, by default for this specific checked-out submodule, create a new detached head?
- If not, what's the right way to push my changes to the repository?

Comment: Commits donot create a detached head. You were on one before the commit. Simply checkout the desired branch before committing.

Answer (score 2):

You can make sure your **[submodule does track a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309)**.
See also "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)"

```
cd /path/to/your/parent/repo
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
```

From there, any `git submodule update --recursive --remote` would update the submodule to the latest of that branch, from where you can make new commits and push back.

Comment: If my submodule is named `my_sm` and is in a subdirectory of the parent repo named `my_subdir1/my_subdir2` and the submodule repo branch I want to track is `my_sm_branch`, then should I write `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.my_subdir1/my_subdir2.branch my_sm_branch`?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, that is the idea.